# Create alternating heading styles in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

I would like to style a Word document with headings that have a border around them, but not for the whole page width.

Something similar to this:
[image: Heading in border, left aligned]

The trick is, on odd pages, I would like the header to be aligned on the right instead of the left.

[image: Heading in border, right aligned]

Sure I could have two styles, left aligned and right aligned... but then I'd have to be careful on which page I'm on, and have to change all the styles for when I add content that shifts content to another page.

Is there a way that allows me to set styles depending on page? It's easy to do with headers, I'm sure there's a way for content.

Comment: Is your issue how create the border (and do you want the shading or is that just to highlight the problem in the question), or just how to make the format even/odd dependent?

Comment: It's making the format even/odd dependent. The images are here just to clarify the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any feature which you could use to set headings as you need, alternate option could be a macro.

Below code goes through all paragraphs of a document and for each having a heading style (outline level is set greater or equal to 1) it sets alignments and vertical borders according to page number.

```
Sub alignHeaders()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim p As Paragraph
    Dim IndentAmount As Single

    IndentAmount = CentimetersToPoints(10) 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        With p
            If .OutlineLevel <> wdOutlineLevelBodyText Then
                If .Range.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber) Mod 2 = 1 Then
                    With .Range.ParagraphFormat
                        .LeftIndent = 0
                        .RightIndent = IndentAmount
                        .Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
                        .Borders(wdBorderRight).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
                    End With
                Else
                    With .Range.ParagraphFormat
                        .RightIndent = 0
                        .LeftIndent = IndentAmount
                        .Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
                        .Borders(wdBorderRight).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next p

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Running the macro:

- you can either place it

  - in your normal.dotm
  - in the documents you want to have this formatting
  - you can create a template file where you define the header styles and also place this macro
- you can assign a hotkey for the macro to run it when you think it's necessary
- you can also set the macro to run automatically before print / save, useful guidance is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702493/how-to-run-a-macro-in-word-before-save) (warning: if you set your macro this way and it's located in normal.dotm then it'll format all the files you save / print!)

Additional note: this macro now change formatting of all paragraphs where outline level is not blank, depending on your objectives you may want to change it. Checking Style names instead of outline levels (e.g. `If Left(.Style,7)="Heading"`) would be an obvious solution, however that wouldn't work in other languages as style names are language dependent.